# TeX: Error: dimension too large

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (6,4);
\draw[decoration={aspect=0.2, segment length=1.5mm, amplitude=1mm,coil},decorate,ultra thick,domain=0:6,smooth] plot[id=sin] function{0.5*sin(2*x)+2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Decorations and smoothed paths don't play together well.

Answer (score 1):

Decorations and smoothed paths don't play nicely.  Instead, increase the number of samples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,fpu}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (6,4);
\draw[
    decoration={
        aspect=0.2,
        segment length=1.5mm,
        amplitude=1mm,
        coil,
    },
    decorate,
    ultra thick,
    domain=0:6,
    samples=55,
    %smooth
] plot[id=sin] function{0.5*sin(2*x)+2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or even better, use the `sin` and `cos` path construction operators (here I drew only one period).  This is much faster because there are a lot fewer low-level operations involved and the accuracy is much higher.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,fpu}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (6,4);
\draw[
    decoration={
        aspect=0.2,
        segment length=1.5mm,
        amplitude=1mm,
        coil,
    },
    decorate,
    ultra thick,
] (0,2) sin (1*pi/4,2.5)
        cos (2*pi/4,2.0)
        sin (3*pi/4,1.5)
        cos (4*pi/4,2.0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]